# LaTeX beamer: Code listings in notes

Tags: latex, beamer

He,

How can I add a code listing to a beamer note slide?

I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
\note{{\tiny{This is a note
      \begin{lstlisting}
foo bar
      \end{lstlisting}}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In what manner does it not work? Errors?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 1):

Verbatim-like commands and environments, which includes lstlisting, cannot appear as arguments to other commands (without losing their magic verbatimness regarding \, $, etc.)

Comment: So there is no way to put marked up code snippets inside beamer notes?